# Getting data from multiple tables in the same Datatable using jQuery Ajax (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have two Models, "User" and "Folder"

```
public class User
{
   public int IdUser { get; set;}
   public string NameUser { get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Folder
{
  public int IdFolder { get; set;}
  public string CodeFolder { get; set;}
  public int IdUser { get; set;}
  public User user { get; set;}
}
```

In the database side the result is obviously something like this : 
"User" with (IdUser : int // NameUser : string) 
and 
"Folder" with (IdFolder : int //NameFolder: string // idUser : int), and it's a One-To-Many Relationship,
so basically, I want to see in the same datatable, the name of the user and the folder associated to him, getting data from two tables and the foreign key that links both of them (which is in my case IdUser that exists in the Folder table)

the script that I run in my view is :

```
        dataTable = $("#dossierTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/MyController/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "JSON"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "IdUser" },
                { "data": "CodeFolder" }
                    "orderable": true,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width":"150px"
                }

            ],
            "language": {

                "emptyTable" : "No results found"
            }
        });
```

In the controller "MyController", the method "GetData" is the following :

```
private MyProjectEntities dbContext = new MyProjectEntities ();

public ActionResult GetData()
{
    dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    List<Folder> folderList = dbContext.Folders.ToList();
    return Json(new { data = folderList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What I'd like is to get the **name** of the User and **NOT his Id**, using "data" : "user.NameUser" in the script doesn't seem to work, I'd like to know how to get the data from the second table